# Ruby global match regexp?

Tags: ruby, regex

In other languages, in RegExp you can use `/.../g` for a global match.

However, in Ruby:

```
"hello hello".match /(hello)/
```

Only captures one hello.

How do I capture all `hello`s?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use the scan method.  The scan method will either give you an array of all the matches or, if you pass it a block, pass each match to the block.

```
"hello1 hello2".scan(/(hello\d+)/)   # => [["hello1"], ["hello2"]]

"hello1 hello2".scan(/(hello\d+)/).each do|m|
  puts m
end
```

I've written about this method, you can read about it [here](http://ruby.about.com/od/regularexpressions/a/regexgrouping.htm) near the end of the article.

Comment: No need to do `each`. Just `.scan(...){|m|...}`

Comment: Great; one additional pointer: if your regex need only be captured as a whole (no subgroups), omitting the enclosing `()` will give you a regular, flat array. If you specify at least 1 subgroup, you'll get a nested array (whose subarrays do NOT include the whole match - only the subgroup captures).

Answer (score 15):

Here's a tip for anyone looking for a way to replace all regex matches with something else.

Rather than the //g flag and one substitution method like many other languages, Ruby uses two different methods instead.

```rb
# .sub — Replace the first
"ABABA".sub(/B/, '') # AABA

# .gsub — Replace all
"ABABA".gsub(/B/, '') # AAA
```

Answer (score 12):

use `String#scan`. It will return an array of each match, or you can pass a block and it will be called with each match.

All the details at http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000812