# Global regex match with backrefs

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to build a regex that matches all consecutive identical digits in a string. For example, given the string `'111221'` I would like matches of `['111', '22', '1']`.

My current regex is `/(\d)\1*/` which works fine with `String#match` but, of course, only returns the first match in the string.

```
'111221'.match /(\d)\1*/ #=> #<MatchData "111" 1:"1">
```

The method given in [Ruby global match regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588931/ruby-global-match-regexp) to get global matches is to use `String#scan` but its behaviour is not what I would expect, presumably because of the capturing group:

```
'111221'.scan /(\d)\1*/ #=> [["1"], ["2"], ["1"]]
```

whereas in other languages, for example Javascript, it works fine:

```
'111221'.match(/(\d)\1*/g) //=> [ "111", "22", "1" ]
```

Is there something fundamentally wrong with my regex or some Ruby functionality that I am missing?

Comment: Have you seen [Match sequences of consecutive characters in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498689/match-sequences-of-consecutive-characters-in-a-string)? You have an identical input string to that question, which is a remarkable coincidence

Comment: That's bizarre! I hadn't seen it, and my example string comes from http://adventofcode.com/day/10 which the question obviously predates by a good few years. The accepted solution is identical to my workaround too. I was hoping for a cleaner solution but I'd be happy to see this closed as a duplicate.