# Need regex to grab everything before and including extension + reject duplicates

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this string:

```
http://www.amazon.com/books-used-books-textbooks/b%3Fie%3DUTF8%26node%3D283155
http://www.amazon.com/gp/site-directory
http://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:GLRqJLrDZEQJ:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%252Ba%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
https://twitter.com/a%3Flang%3Den
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:4teZIJ7lbgsJ:https://twitter.com/a%3Flang%253Den%252Ba%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/a
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:Pn8j0e0faiAJ:http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/a%252Ba%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
http://boards.4chan.org/a/
```

I need to grab all the information upto where the ".com", ".org", or ".net" ends.

The expected output should look like this:

```
http://www.amazon.com/
https://en.wikipedia.org/
http://dictionary.reference.com/
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/
http://boards.4chan.org/
```

So far I've tried a few things:

- `/(\/)([^\/]+)\Z/`
- `^(http[s]?)(...)\w{3}\`
- `/https?:\/\/[\S]/`

None of them worked, so now I'm here. If there's an easier way to do it please let me know. I also need to reject the duplicates if there are any.

Comment: Your original question included de-duping. You may be aware (since you've edited your question) that regex won't de-dupe for you. Since you've tagged your question with Ruby I've included the `uniq` in my answer that you'd need in order to de-dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex I use for capturing the different parts of URLs is:

```
^(?<uri_schema_and_host>(?<uri_scheme>https|http):\/\/(?<uri_host>[^\/]+))(?<uri_path>\/[^?]*?)?(?<uri_query>\?.*)?$
```

This creates named captures for many parts of the URL. We can shorten this a bit for your needs to:

```
^((https|http):\/\/[^\/]+).*$
```

In Ruby you can easily utilise this using the [`scan` method on String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) and use `uniq` to then de-dupe the results:

```
regex = /^(?<uri_schema_and_host>(?<uri_scheme>https|http):\/\/(?<uri_host>[^\/]+))(?<uri_path>\/[^?]*?)?(?<uri_query>\?.*)?$/m

results = text.scan regex

scheme_and_hosts = results.map {|x| x[0].to_s }
scheme_and_hosts.uniq!

scheme_and_hosts.each {|x| puts x }
```

The `/.../m` at the end of the regex within the ruby script matches each line separately, so `scan` will find a match on each line.

Comment: This is a great answer except it keeps telling me that I have unmatched close parenthesis?

Comment: Hmmm, it works for me: https://repl.it/BtUK/0 If you're having problems you might need to post a bit more of your code so we can assist.

Comment: Your regex won't ignore duplicates, the question specifically asked to do it by regex and not Ruby code. Although, since your answer got accepted I guess OP was alright with that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module (`s` is your string):

```
require 'uri'

s.split(/\n/).map { |line|
    uri = URI(line)
    uri.scheme + "://" + uri.host
}.uniq
```

Note: if your string comes from a file, you don't need to use split:

```
File.open('yourfile').map { |line|
    uri = URI(line)
    uri.scheme + "://" + uri.host
}.uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent wheels, reuse existing ones:

```
require 'uri'

%w[
  http://www.amazon.com/books-used-books-textbooks/b%3Fie%3DUTF8%26node%3D283155
  http://www.amazon.com/gp/site-directory
  http://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A
  http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:GLRqJLrDZEQJ:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%252Ba%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
  https://twitter.com/a%3Flang%3Den
  http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:4teZIJ7lbgsJ:https://twitter.com/a%3Flang%253Den%252Ba%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/a
  http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:Pn8j0e0faiAJ:http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/a%252Ba%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
  http://boards.4chan.org/a/
].map{ |s|
  scheme, _, host = URI.split(s)
  "#{ scheme }://#{ host }"
}.uniq
# => ["http://www.amazon.com", "https://en.wikipedia.org", "http://webcache.googleusercontent.com", "https://twitter.com", "http://dictionary.reference.com", "http://boards.4chan.org"]
```

If your data is in a string, then split it into lines and iterate over them:

```
str = "foo
bar
baz"

str.lines.map(&:rstrip)
# => ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`/^(http[s]?:\/\/[^\/]*)\//` will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you need to avoid duplicates makes it a bit complicated:

```
/(?:^|\n)(https?:\/\/[^\/]*?\.(?:com|org|net)\/?)(?!(?:.|\n)*\n\1)/
```

First, `(?:^|\n)` checks whether or not it is a beginning of a new line, as we don't want to match anything in the middle of a line. Then we begin capturing our group with `(`. We match `http`, and `s`, if it exists, followed by a colon and two escaped slashes `:\/\/`. We then capture everything except a slash, with a lazy behavior - capturing as little as we can. Here we could capture any character, however a slash is a good indication that we've gone too far, so we don't want that. Then we capture an escaped dot `\.` followed by a non-capturing group, which allows us to have either com, org, or net: `(?:com|org|net)`. Finally, if there is a trailing, backslash, `\/?` captures it too, and the capturing group closes with `)`.

This is where it gets interesting. While we've successfully captured our links, we want to avoid any duplicates. For this, we employ a negative look-ahead. We assert that we don't want to find:

- Any characters, even new line feeds `(?:.|\n)`, taking as many as we can, followed by:
- A new line `\n`, followed by
- **The whole capture group that we just captured.**

The last bit is very important - this is how we ensure we don't get any duplicates. If we just matched e.g. `amazon.com`, and `amazon.com` exists anywhere ahead, it won't be captured. As such, only the last instance of `amazon.com` will be captured.

A graphical visualization may help understanding it even better:
[image: A graphical visualization of the regex string]

Comment: That's pretty smart. I hadn't thought of a look-ahead having the ability to use the capture. Seems a little less readable, but technically correct. I opted to answer with code as I saw 13aal  was using Ruby and it is easy to do the processing on the results.

Comment: @dsample And it's probably much faster - this Regex took 26109 steps to go through OP's original test data. I only did this example because OP asked for no duplicates using regex explicitly, and because most people probably don't know this trick, and I though it would be useful for readers to see. In production code, it wouldn't be *that smart* to use this kind of solution.

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis I really like this answer, however, it tells me that -g is an unknown regex option

Comment: @13aal Ah, sorry, I didn't know Ruby doesn't have the global search modifier! I edited it out. You can use `.scan` to achieve the same functionality, see more on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588931/ruby-global-match-regexp)